# Why reportNG does not show reason/stacktrace for skipped test

Tags: reportng

I have integrated `reportNG` with `testNG` framework by adding following lines in `testNG.xml`.

Scenario:

I made a mistake by not writing correct dataProvider name in test annotation. This caused test to skip. Original `testNG` showed the reason for skipping test, where as `reportNG` report does not show the exception/reason for skipping test. The following exception was displayed in `testNG->index.html:`

```
org.testng.TestNGException: Method public void com.cigniti.paytm.test.TestLogin.testSecureLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) requires a DataProvider named : getSecureLoginData ... Removed 21 stack frames
```

Question: How can I ensure `reportNG` shows the exception/reason for skipping tests?